# Nodemon doesn't start the server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I installed nodemon to devDependencies and set the script `"start" : "nodemon server.js"`. However, when I do `npm start`, it throws me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\win10\Desktop\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! question-answer-rest-api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the question-answer-rest-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "question-answer-rest-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Back end project for practice",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Express",
    "Nodejs",
    "Mongoose",
    "Api"
  ],
  "author": "Cihan Özcan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

I also filled in server.js and tried that way but it didn't work.

**My server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

There are no any file in the folder. I couldn't find similar error in SO. I installed nodemon as global and checked the global environment in pc. There is no problem with it.

What is the problem ?

Comment: I tried this in Windows and in an empty node:14 docker container and it works just fine.  I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try

```
npm uninstall nodemon
```

Then

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

It should works

Comment: I don't think the intent was ever to install nodemon globally.  The point is that the script should have worked, and indeed it *does* work on a clean system.  So something is fishy with the asker's setup.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer smuggles in the idea of installing nodemon globally, which is not necessary to solve your problem.  Although _uninstalling_ an existing nodemon may very well have solved the problem.  So it's half plausibly correct, but half misleading.  Other readers may not wish to install nodemon globally to solve a similar problem.